# get records from yesterday from log table

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, date, time

Scenario:

log table with a considerable amount of records (2 Million) with a timestamp field.
no indexes except for the ID as a primary key, and index (or any other persistent object) creation is out of the question

I want to select all records from yesterday.

I know there are a few ways of doing it, I just would like opinion on the "best" way, and by best I mean fastest.

the trick here is the "time" of the timestamp, because if now is 11AM and I do something like:

```
where modifiedDate between dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Ill get records only from yesterday at 11 and will get data from today

Its sql 2005 so there is no "Date" datatype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM  myTable
WHERE modifiedDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),-1)
    AND modifiedDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/229e0/2) with Demo

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   modifiedDate >= DATEADD(dd, -1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
        AND modifiedDate < CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```